# How did Fermat find tangent lines of Folium of Descartes?

Tags: mathematics, mathematicians, fermat

The wikipedia article about Folium of Descartes says:

> Descartes challenged Pierre de Fermat to find the tangent line to the
> curve at an arbitrary point since Fermat had recently discovered a
> method for finding tangent lines. Fermat solved the problem easily,
> something Descartes was unable to do.

I want to know how Fermat found the tangent line and where it is written.

Comment: Wikipedia also has an article on Fermat's method. It is called [adequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adequality) and amounts to adding infinitesimals to the variable and then setting them equal to zero after cancellations.

Comment: I Goggled Adequacy and tangent. A lot of articles.

Comment: If y is written as a function of x, I understand how to do adequality method. Did he use parametrization? I want to know where he wrote his solution.

Comment: For a polynomial curve, a tangent at a point  is a line through that point with contact of order $2$ or more.  The order of contact for a polynomial is easy, and could be done before derivatives were commonly used.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar However, I think the relation between algebraic order and geometric tangency is not trivial. What did Fermat think about that?

Comment: Can this be done for all (parametrized) curves?